# Is there one Windows System Message Queue or Multiple?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am reading a excerpt from - [Charles Petzold's book on C++ Windows](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/petzold/ch06c.htm)

It states

> When you press a key, Windows places either a WM_KEYDOWN or
>   WM_SYSKEYDOWN message in the message queue of the window with the
>   input focus. When you release a key, Windows places either a WM_KEYUP
>   or WM_SYSKEYUP message in the message queue.

I am confused by this.

Am I right in saying there is only One Windows System Message Queue, and `x` Application queues for `x` Applications.

And that Windows always places either of the two `WM_*KEYDOWN` messages into the Windows System Message Queue(regardless of input focus), and after moves message's from this Queue into the Application Message queue(app Queue chosen via the HWND in the msg structure)

Doesn't the excerpt implicitly state that there are multiple Message queues, and one is chosen from input focus?

Comment: I don't see anything that suggests the existence of a system wide message queue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In that case is there a System Message queue and Application Message Queue for every window?

Comment: No. Each thread has zero or one message queues.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Another excerpt in the book states *"However, these messages are not placed in an application's message queue right away. Instead, Windows stores these messages in something called the system message queue"*. Doesn't this imply a system wide message queue, and multiple application based message queues?

Comment: I can't see enough context to that quote. Anyway, why are you asking.

Comment: There is a system-wide hardware input queue. A diagram can be found at [When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773).

Comment: OK, read this. MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#quequed_messages says that messages go first into a single system wide queue, then get handed off to thread queue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was asking because I am trying to build a mental image, however I cant if I am incorrectly understanding *parts* (or if the *parts* im reading about are not described clearly). After reading the above, it appears there is one single system message queue, and zero or one thread-specific message queue. The resource link you gave provides excellent info, cleared up alot! Many thanks!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Each Win32 thread (that is, after the first USER/GDI call the initializes win32k state) has **at least** 2 queues: one for "sent" messages and one for "posted" messages. That's clear from the documentation. (Also see [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130530-00/?p=4213/).) In fact, each Win32 thread quite a few queues, for example: `psmsSent`, `psmsReceiveList` and `mlPost` (and `pq`, which I don't remember if contains messages or something a little different). If you have Windows 7 you can see all that in `win32k.pdb` and in Skywing's WinDbg extension.

Comment: @conio Dang it, had my mental image built until you said that. Guess theres more to understand, Thanks for posting!

Comment: Note that the second part of my comment to David was strictly an implementation detail that shouldn't be of much interest unless you're researching or debugging win32k. For the most part knowing about "queued messages" and "nonqueued messages" should be enough. See [About Messages and Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx) (it's the page David linked earlier) and [The posted message queue vs the input queue vs the message queue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130530-00/?p=4213/).

Comment: @conio: Your first link to The Old New Thing points out, that there need not be distinct queues. You can contrive an algorithm that works with a single queue just fine. You can also think up a different algorithm that works with multiple queues. Either one can serve to build a mental model that matches the observable behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable: *You* **can** contrive anything. Won't make it true, though. The **observable behavior** is more than just the **documented contract**. That's why I noted that *in fact* these are separate queues. `mlPost` is the separate queue for posted messages. Also note, for example, that in Raymond's first algorithm, *let n = the first non-member in the queue;* either requires going through all the "member" elements in the queue (which has observable performance ramifications) or holding a pointer into the first "non-member" element in the queue. Which is practically having two queues.

Comment: @conio: This question is about building a mental model. You can pick either of the models Raymond lays out in his blog entry. Once you have established a mental model you can ponder about performance implications of either one. Performance is not part of the observable behavior. In fact, performance isn't even behavior at all.

Comment: @IInspectable: No. The question is about what happens in actuality. It is Raymond Chen's post that speaks of "mental models", not the question. To the claim that the performance ramifications of doing O(n) lookup instead of O(1) are not observable I won't even bother to reply...

Comment: @conio: No one claimed, that performance characteristics weren't observable. They are. That doesn't turn performance into behavior, though. And this question is asking about behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable: No. The question is about what happens in actuality. It is Raymond Chen's post that speaks of "mental models", not the question. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/behavior

Comment: @conio: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815232/is-there-one-windows-system-message-queue-or-multiple?noredirect=1#comment70819546_41815232) (*"I was asking because I am trying to build a mental image"*)? Anyway, that Oxford Dictionaries link doesn't seem to contradict anything I said.

Comment: @IInspectable: I have. That was not part of the question, but rather a comment. That wasn't the question itself, but rather the *motivation* for the question. Moreover, I replied to David comment rather than to the question itself. There are **in fact** several queues for each Win32 thread. No amount of spamming by you would change that; only an architecture change by Microsoft. Different mental images or models may serve different purposes and may be of varying correctness, usefulness or validity. One queue as David said is manifestly not as accurate as what actually happens (more than one).